# How to change a password in ROR if using acts_as_authentic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passwords

I am using the plugin acts_as_authentic!Then i want to design a page to change the password!And I don't know how to deal with it!
First,how to test and verify the old password?
Then,when it gets wrong ,does any validations should be made?
sorry for My poor English! Maybe I don't make it clear!
Any comments would be appreciated!
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I user auth logic, but checking the old password is just the same. Your User model should have a salt field, so all you need to do is encrypt the string

```
params[:password] + current_user.salt
```

using whatever encryption acts_as_authentic is configured to use. You can check what your Users' salt field is called simply by using the rails console and typing User.new. Hope that helps.